# iTerm2 not using the default shell specified by chsh

Tags: macos

So, I've a Macbook Air M2 running the latest MacOS as of this post (Sonoma 14.0).
I've installed homebrew and iTerm2. Within iTerm, I used homebrew to install the latest bash version (5.2.15(1)-release). Post install, I see it's using /opt/homebrew/bin/bash as the full path, so I added this to /etc/shells which looks like this:

> cat /etc/shells
> List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
> Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
> one of these shells.
>
> /bin/bash
> /bin/csh
> /bin/dash
> /bin/ksh
> /bin/sh
> /bin/tcsh
> /bin/zsh
> /opt/homebrew/bin/bash

I then used chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash which seems to have worked, until I use bash --version (after closing and reopening iTerm2).

> bash --version
> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)

But this output shows latest version:

> /opt/homebrew/bin/bash --version
> GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin23.0.0)
> Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>
> This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
> There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

What am I doing wrong here?

I also changed the default profile within iTerm2 to reflect the new path, but it appears this hasn't changed much.
[image]

Comment: This question would be on-topic on [Ask Different.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The output of `bash --version` shows what version is run when you use `bash` as a command, not what you're using as your interactive shell. It is controlled by the `PATH` variable in your interactive shell, which has nothing to do with what's selected with `chsh`, etc. To see what version of bash you're running in right now, use `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`. To see what's run when you use `bash` as a command, use `type bash` (or `type -a bash` to also see other bashes lower in the `PATH` priority order).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (`macOS 14.1.1 Sonoma`), new iTerm2 windows would use the macOS version of bash (`/bin/bash`) instead of the brew version(`/opt/homebrew/bin/bash`).  This was confirmed using `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Turns out in my iTerm Profile -> General -> Command it was set to `Command: /bin/bash --login` and so new windows ignored the setting in chsh.  It was set this way because of problems launching a login shell in the past.

The solution is to set it to `Login Shell` which will use the shell set by chsh.

Comment: I realized that it was an iTerm2 problem, and not the OS, when I launched an xterm and it used the correct shell.